# I need to use Intgers to draw multiple lines on a map

Tags: jython-2.7

I need to add lines to a .png map using jython (JES) using integers for how many cities and another for enter the number of the city which goes from 0-9, I have to use the X & Y coordinates below (ie 0 = 45,310) things look ok up until the second integer, then my coding is off from that point. I appreciate any help thanks.

```
import random

def mapLevel1():

  file=pickAFile()
  mapLevel1=makePicture(file)

  city1=requestInteger("How many cities would you like to visit?")
  cityNum=requestInteger("Enter the number of the city")

  cityXValue=[ 45, 95,182,207,256,312,328,350,374,400]
  cityYValue=[310,147, 84,201,337,375,434,348,335,265]

  0=addLine(mapLevel1,45,310)
  1=addLine(mapLevel1,95,147)
  2=addLine(mapLevel1,182,84)
  3=addLine(mapLevel1,207,201)
  4=addLine(mapLevel1,256,337)
  5=addLine(mapLevel1,312,375)
  6=addLine(mapLevel1,328,434)
  7=addLine(mapLevel1,350,348)
  8-addLine(mapLevel1,374,335)
  9=addLine(maplevel1,400,265)

    if 0
      print cityXValue[0]
      print cityYValue[0]

    if cityNum=1
      print cityXValue[1]
      print cityYValue[1]

    if cityNum=2
      print cityXValue[2]
      print cityYValue[2]

    if cityNum=3
      print cityXValue[3]
      print cityYValue[3]

    if cityNum=4
      print cityXValue[4]
      print cityYValue[4]

    if cityNum=5
      print cityXValue[5]
      print cityYValue[5]

    if cityNum=6
      print cityXValue[6]
      print cityYValue[6]

    if cityNum=7
      print cityXValue[7]
      print cityYValue[7]

    if cityNum=8
      print cityXValue[8]
      print cityYValue[8]

    if cityNum=9
      print cityXValue[9]
      print cityYValue[9]

  return mapLevel1
```

Comment: Could you kindly give us your expected and actual output, and any errors you are getting

Comment: my output is that writing a program for a travel agent we are given a map with the x and y values (207,201) is city 3 on the map, by using requestIngeger the user can enter multiple inputs and have to draw lines on the map between cities.  I can get the requestIntegers to work but unable to draw the lines